# Magento2 : How to show the product's attribute value at product details page on PORTO theme?

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2.4

I have create drop-down attribute on the name of `location` with drop-down options.

I'd like to show the value of this attribute at product details page above add to cart.

Copied the file addtocart.phtml from the below location:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

to my theme like below:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

I added my attribute code for my custom attribute like below :

```
<?= $_product->getAttributeText('location'); ?> //For dropdown
```

But it is not showing the data.

My product's url is :

http://www.depoto.com/vizag/sample-one.html

Comment: You can copy the addtocart.phtml from vendor directory and call your custom attribute value according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file addtocart.phtml from the below location:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

to your theme like below:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Then you can add your code for your custom attribute like below :

```
<?= $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); ?> //For dropdown
<?= $_product->getData('attribute_code'); ?> //For text
```

***Note: Write your custom code anywhere on this page but after the line `<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>`***

**UPDATED:**

As you are using PORTO theme then you need to copy the file to below location:

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Comment: I think you are using theme. Can you check if any other addtocart.phtml is calling from the theme? You can check the exact file name by enabling the template path hint.

Comment: Did you copy the file to app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml location?

Comment: yes brother, i just figuredout. i copied at vendor location. thank you. please updae the answer with your above comment.

Comment: Yes. Its updated now.